# Symfony 2 security voters displaying a lot of messages in log

Tags: security, symfony, logging

I'm not quite familiar with symfony2 security voters and I'm having a lot of `security.INFO: No expression found; abstaining from voting. [] []` in my log files in each request.

What does it means and what can I do to correct it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is the `ExpressionVoter` of the [`JMSSecurityExtraBundle`](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSecurityExtraBundle/master/expressions) which provides nice expressions for granting access, better than simple role decisions. As you configured no expression in config or programmatic this log results.

If you want to know more about security voters, or maybe implement some self, you can read this [symfony cookbook article](http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/cookbook/security/voters.html).

Comment: Thanks, @Pazi! I'll check how configure this expression and I tell you if it worked! ;)

Comment: You don't need to use expressions. This can be additions to the normal acl. The above logentry is normal, as your are using the bundle.

Comment: in each request I get this 5 lines: `[2013-05-30 02:55:49] security.INFO: Populated SecurityContext with an anonymous Token [] []
[2013-05-30 02:55:49] security.INFO: No expression found; abstaining from voting. [] []
[2013-05-30 02:55:49] security.INFO: No expression found; abstaining from voting. [] []
[2013-05-30 02:55:49] security.INFO: No expression found; abstaining from voting. [] []
[2013-05-30 02:55:49] security.INFO: No expression found; abstaining from voting. [] []`. Is this really normal? I want to clean my auth log of this lines. Is it possible? Thanks!